# How to check linux script job run history from past month or week or last from 3 days in putty

Tags: linux

Hot check linux job run history ? Is there way any other command ?

Like how many times it ran with date and time.

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569).  Also see [help/on-topic] for the kind of questions that are on topic, and [ask].

Comment: What do you mean by "job"? How is this problem related to any device driver?

Comment: These are Cron job scheduled in linux server. I jsut want check job run history. I wanted any specific command to check ?

Comment: If they are cronjob on linux server, you can check log in /var/log/cron, your job might also want to redirect log into file

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My ask is, in Linux set of Cron job scheduled I want to know histotry  of cron jonbs run. Ex: date and time when it run etc... So for this is there any specific linux command to check ?